# Why sometimes the richTextBox is blinking?

Tags: c#

Im updating in the richTextBox two variables and since i dont want it to move to a new line each time im doing a Clear() to the richTextbox.
But every few seconds in the richextBox is like blinking when clearing it.
Before Clear() i used: richTextBox1.Text = ""; but it gave the same result.

Is there any way to avoid that ?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            memUsage = theMemCounter.NextValue();
            label1.Text = memUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Memory Usage   " + memUsage.ToString());
            AppendText(richTextBox1, "Memory Usage   " + memUsage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine, Color.Red);
            cpuUsage = this.theCPUCounter.NextValue();
            label2.Text = cpuUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Cpu Usage   " + this.cpuUsage.ToString());
            AppendText(richTextBox1, "Cpu Usage   " + cpuUsage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine, Color.Blue);
            Values.Add(cpuUsage);
            isProcessRunning();
            if (alreadyRun == true)
            {
                processValues.Add(cpuUsage);
            }

        }
```

Maybe i should use something else then richTextBox ? Im using richTextBox to color the text inside.

This is the AppendText function:

```
public  void AppendText( RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }
```

Comment: Depends on what does AppendText() method do. Is there any code that is time consuming? Or maybe is the problem in constant repainting.

Comment: What's `AppendText` method doing? Can you show us the code?

Comment: Nikola i just added the AppendText code ot my question.

Comment: Try setting your form's `DoubleBuffered` property to `true`